# I've an app with AdMobs in Google Play but I have doubts

Tags: android-layout, admob, dpi, android-resolution

I've an app with AdMobs in Google Play but I have doubts.
PX DP converter is a simple tool for developers and designers. 
Basically this application is for my learning.

[PX DP Converter | Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=projectes.edoyle.pxdpconverter)

I have understood that if I use AdMobs I can't see or click on the advertising or google will ban my account.
I specified in "TestDevice" the emulator and id of my terminal, so I see a banner instead of advertising and the advertising appears in others smartphones, it works correctly. (sorry for my bad English)

My questions are ...

1. I have a couple of smartphones with different accounts.
   Can I click on advertising using local wi-fi (home) without getting banned?
2. can i use the app with advertising without register my ID on "TestDevice" while I don't click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I doubt that Admob is likely to ban you for a few test clicks on your development device. But they do have algorithms that track and detect aberrant clicks so if you abuse this they will catch and ban you.
2. Yes